# Query conversion from Oracle SQL to Spark SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the oracle SQL query,
that has to_date() function and adds with some days

```
select    
      to_date('01.01.1960','dd.MM.yyyy') + (1767097320000000/1000000/3600/24) as ACTUAL,
      '2015-12-30 12:22:00' AS RESULT
from DUAL
```

Output

```
-----------------------------------------------
| ACTUAL                | RESULT              |
----------------------------------------------|    
|2015-12-30 12:22:00    | 2015-12-30 12:22:00 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

My seek is to convert the above oracle query `to_date('01.01.1960','dd.MM.yyyy') + (1767097320000000/1000000/3600/24)` in spark SQL.

Comment: I don't know Spark SQL. With that said: a 15 second Google search revealed that Spark supports a `TO_DATE(<string>)` function, and it has a `DATE_ADD(<start_date, days>)` function to add a number of days to an input date. So, I wonder what **you** tried - since I was able to find everything you need in less than a minute, without knowing Spark SQL. Please add what you attempted to your question, and an explanation of how your attempt failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks the same with the given datetime format.

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01.01.1960', "dd.MM.yyyy") + (1767097320000000/1000000), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as RESULT,
        '2015-12-30 12:22:00' as EXPECTED
""").show

+-------------------+-------------------+
|             RESULT|           EXPECTED|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2015-12-30 12:22:00|2015-12-30 12:22:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 

DATE_FORMAT(CAST(CAST(CAST(to_date('1960-01-01 00:00:00') AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE)+ (1767097320000000/1000000) AS TIMESTAMP), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as RESULT

,'2015-12-30 12:22:00' as RESULT

from dual;
```

We have to convert the date string `'1960-01-01 00:00:00'` to timestamp object and then cast as double type.

Next, sum the milliseconds `1767097320000000/1000000` and the date as a double value.

The final value which is a double then cast as timestamp again

Another solution

`date_format(CAST(unix_timestamp('1960-01-01 00:00:00')+ (1767097320000000/1000000) AS TIMESTAMP), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as RESULT`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.